# Command Button () should be clicked only when certain sheet available

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting data on daily basis. For that I use different command buttons to filer data and gather data from different sheets. Already kept made around 25 command buttons on first sheet. My issue is e.g. command button say 20 should not be work or should not be click until unless sheet no. 20 available. Currently I am using

```
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
j = Worksheets.Count
For k = 20 To 20
With Worksheets(k)
```

Sometimes by mistake I click on command button which particular sheet not available and code does not generate any data.

Comment: When you open the workbook, sheet 20 is not present the button 20 should be disabled?

Comment: show your button code to let us help you more effectively

Comment: You can loop through/set particular command buttons to make them Dis/Enable, In/Visible - `WorksheetObject.Buttons("name" or number)`

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like below?
Obviously you need to replace the "20" with whatever your sheet name is and 
and you will put this code in your click handler

```
Dim isWorlsheetAvailable
isWorlsheetAvailable = False
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name = "20" Then
        isWorlsheetAvailable = True
    End If
Next i

If Not isWorlsheetAvailable Then
    MsgBox ("sdffd")
    Exit Sub
End If
Do your work here......
```